# Can create Files but not Directories on external storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I've got an application which writes large files to an external USB drive. The directory to write these files to comes from `context.getExternalMediaDirs()`, so it normally ends up being something like `/storage/<UUID>/Android/media/com.app.package/`.

My problem is that on all devices I've tested so far, this works. However, on a Sony Bravia TV (running Android 8.0) I am able to create files in the external media directory, but if I call `mkdirs()` to create a directory it always returns false.

My application targets API 28, declares the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions, and requests them both from the user at runtime.

It also seems that this problem goes away if I allow the Sony TV to "format the device as external storage", however this formats it to FAT32 which imposes file size limits that are unacceptable for my application.

Formatting the drive to NTFS via a PC allows files to be created, but not directories.

I suspect this is indicative of a bug in Sony's implementation, but I'd like some feedback from the community.

Has anyone encountered this on other devices? Is there a potential work around?

It doesn't make sense to me that I'd be allowed to create a file, but not a directory.

Comment: FAT32 cannot store large file over 4GB. Then i think you should split it.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that FAT32 imposes a 4GB limit on the size of files. Unfortunately, that will break my application. I included the note about FAT32 as a data point since it seems that when the drive is formatted by the system (as FAT32), the permissions are different and I'm allowed to create directories.